# writing script The first parameter: file/directory,the other parameters: commands

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I want to create a script that receives a list of parameters in the following structure:

- The first parameter: file or directory
- The other parameters: the names of the commands in the system, for example `date`, `pwd`, `tail`, `head`, `ls`.

The script will run all the commands (starting from the second parameter) on the file/directory received as the first parameter.

I tried this script but I can't use the commands options like `-l -i -n`
so how can i do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
shift

for cmd in "$@" 
do
    if [ -e $name ]
    then
        echo Executing:$cmd
        ($cmd $name)2>/dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then
            echo error
        fi
    else
        exit 7
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`getopts` or `getopt` is the answer.

`getopts` works on short keys, `-i` for example and easier to work with. It is also builtin to bash and always available.

`getopt` is an external tool, it can work with long parameters like `--input-file`, and a little harder to use. This is an external tool and in theory can be absent, but...

Read here for easy tutorial:
https://dustymabe.com/2013/05/17/easy-getopt-for-a-bash-script/